# Error when trying to disable a button in ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor4.x

I'am trying do disable a button dynamically on page load whne some checks are done, but the editor is instance is undefined. I load in the page of the page :

```
ckeditor.js
CKEDITOR.replace( 'message', {
    customConfig: 'ckeditor_config'
});
check.js
```

In the file check.js is there i'am trying to disable button dynamically :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var pollcatid = jQuery('#poll_catid').val();

    if(pollcatid !== undefined)
    {
        CKEDITOR.instances.message.getCommand( 'polls' ).enable();
    }
    else
    {
        CKEDITOR.instances.message.getCommand( 'polls' ).disable();
    }
});
```

On page load i have the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.message.getCommand(...) is undefined
```

So why at i have an error in the file check.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to it, by doing like that :

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt){
        // Do your bindings and other actions here for example
        // You can access each editor that this event has fired on from the event
        var editor = evt.editor;

        var pollcatid = jQuery('#poll_catid').val();

        if(pollcatid !== undefined)
        {
            editor.getCommand( 'polls' ).enable();
        }
        else
        {
            editor.getCommand( 'polls' ).disable();
        }
});
```